# Keep href and anchor on click in sync

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, anchor, href

**Previous Code:**

```
[anchor-Tag]href="'<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Url") %>'"
```

Now I wanted to append few other things from my current anchors parent element so i am passing 'this' to function which does other things and append it to url.

**Code Now:**

```
[anchor-Tag]href="#" onclick="$.redirectToDetailsPage('<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Url") %>', this)"
```

The problem is this `[anchor-tag]`'s `href` is being accessed from multiple js and now its coming as empty since i am doing same work by onclick.

So, i want to keep href intact. Is it possible?

Comment: What is this code? It's not javascript and it doesn't appear to use Knockout.

Comment: It is ASP.NET web forms repeater.

Comment: Can i call javascript function to fill href value?